# How to solve for maximum area of a rectangle under a curve?

Tags: calculus, functions, optimization

Having trouble with this optimization question and was hoping I could get some help with it. The function of the curve is $8^{-\frac{x}{5}}$. I would greatly appreciate a full explanation.

I already have that: $A = W \times H$, $A = 2x \times 8^{-\frac{x}{5}}$, $A = 16 x^{-\frac{x}{5}}$.

I think the derivative of this is $\displaystyle \frac{-16\log x - 16}{5} \frac{x^x}{5}$, and in order to get the maximum I have to set it equal to $0$ and solve for it, but I'm somewhat stuck.

Comment: I'm confused as to why the area would be $2x \times 8^{-\frac{x}{5}}$. Is the rectangle bound by $x = 0$ and $y = 0$? If so, it should be $x \times 8^{-\frac{x}{5}}$, I think.

Comment: If you are ok, you can accept the answer and set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since $8^{-\frac{x}{5}}>0$, for $x\ge 0$ the area is given by $$A(x)=x\cdot 8^{-\frac{x}{5}}$$

the derivative is given by

$$A(x)=x\cdot 8^{-\frac{x}{5}}=e^{\log x-\frac{x}{5}\log8}$$

$$A'(x)=e^{\log x-\frac{x}{5}\log8} \cdot \left(\log x-\frac{x}{5}\log8\right)'=8^{-x/5}\left(\frac1x-\frac{1}{5}\log8\right)=0 \implies \frac1x-\frac{1}{5}\log8=0 \implies x=\frac{5}{\log 8}\\\implies A_{MAX}=\frac{5}{\log 8}\cdot 8^{-\frac{1}{\log 8}}=\frac{5}{\log 8}\cdot 8^{-\log_8e}=\frac{5}{e\log 8}$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the area is $x 8^{-x/5}$.  Take logarithms to obtain

$$\log x - (x\log 8)/5,$$

which is maximized at $x=5/\log 8$,

which (if I didn't screw things up) yields

$5/(e\log 8)$.

Comment: Do you think you might be able to explain this one a little more in depth? I was trying to find the local maximum using the derivative of the function, how does using logarithms help me get the area?

Comment: It helps you find the location of the maximum, not the area itself.  If a function $f$ is maximized at $m$ then so is $\log f$.  In this case maximizing $\log f$ seemed easier.  I then plugged the $x$ obtained back into the original area formula, i.e. $x8^{-x/5}$.